# UI router + node/express JS page reloading unwantedly

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

I have a strange issue with UI router and Express interacting together.
I've looked for solutions everywhere but nothing seems to be completely fixing the issue working.

When my app is in my /public folder and when i navigate to / it works fine and the url is getting changed as i click links.But whenever i go directly to /random/path ( `ui-sref="post/new">` ), it get intercepted by nodejs and say that this route doesn't exist.

I've fixed that issue using from a topic on that issue :

```
    app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));


    app.use(function (req, res) {
        res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/');
    });
```

And now everything is working fine whenever i navigate directly to the path i want.

Now there is a new issue where the whole page will reload on every path change instead of just behaving like a client side app should and just load the view + controller.

The strange thing is that it's working as expected for 2 or 3 path.

Can anyone help ?

edit :

```
    angular.module('App').config(function($stateProvider, $locationProvider,$urlRouterProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
        $stateProvider
            .state('posts-new', {
                url:'/post/new',
                templateUrl: 'tmpl1.html'
            })
            .state('posts', {
                url:'/posts',
                templateUrl: 'tmpl2.html'
            });
    });
```

I've also tried with both base url /  and   `<base href="/index.html">`

Comment: Could you include your ui-router configuration? I suspect you might want to add an otherwise clause.

Comment: done hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so your NodeJS route not existing is because of your route.
It works fine for `/` because it interprets that as `/public/index.html`.
If you then try and load `/post/new`, it looks for `/public/post/new/index.html` - and doesn't find it.
Fix below should work for you.

```
app.use(function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html');
});
```

Then, you'll need a slightly separate way of serving your templates - basically as static files! I'd personally suggest you use a simple folder for templates, as shown below. Make sure this is **above** your catchall route above.

```
app.use('/templates', express.static('/public/templates'));
```

Oh, and finally - you'll want your `<base>` tag set to `/`.

Comment: You'll need all parts together - If you only have 1 of them done, it will still break. Specifically, if you don't have both _either_ your base HTML file, or your templates won't load properly which leads to your reloading issue.

Comment: what part am i missing ? it's not clear , i have all three parts but i might be missing something important. I have base href , template , etc. everything.
It just that when clicked throught ui-sref the whole page will reload ( in some case only ), but still serve the proper route. Pointing the browser directly at any route do work already. It's just that when clicked trhought ui-sref it reloads the page instead of just loading the controller + template.

Comment: Try `ui-sref="posts-new"`? UI-Router docs seem to use the state name rather than URL.

Comment: It was a typo ;/ it's ` ui-sref="posts-new" `  so.. still the same :(((..  , also as i said in the op  it does work on some of the routes.